# Error con "main" no definida en linux ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

acabo de instalar ubuntu en mi pc y quise programar desde la consola y para ello instale un notepad (se llama notepadqq)
al momento de ejecutar yo un programa simple manda error

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf ("Hello world");

    return 0;
}
```

Despues de guardarlo como `nombre.c`, ejecuto lo siguiete:

> gcc nombre.c

El error que salta al compilar desde la consola de linux es:

> En la función '_start': (.text+0x20): referencia a 'main' sin definir
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: El archivo esta guardado como ".c", el compilador lo estoy llamando de la siguiente forma ` gcc nombre.c`

Comment: Asegurate de que el fichero `nombre.c` tiene lo que crees. Desde la consola pon `cat nombre.c` para verlo. Quizás tu editor lo guardó con otro nombre, y el .c está en realidad vacío.

Answer (score 1):

No has declarado la función `main` de la manera que el compilador la espera. Según el [estándar de C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (traducción mía):

> #### 5.1.2.2.1 Inicio del programa.
>
> 1. La función llamada al inicio del programa recibe el nombre de `main`. La implementación no declara ningún prototipo de esta función. Debe ser definida con `int` como tipo de retorno y sin parámetros:
>
>    ```
>    int main(void) { /* ... */ }
>    ```
>
>    o con dos parámetros (referidos aquó como `argc` y `argv`, aunque se puede usar cualquier nombre dado que son locales a la función en que son declarados):
>
>    ```
>    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
>    ```
>
>    o equivalente; o de alguna otra manera dependiente de implementación.

Tú no has declarado `int main(void)` si no que has declarado `int main()`. La diferencia es importante ya que en C una función con una lista de parámetros vacía se interpreta como que no se sabe cuántos parámetros recibe (puede ser ninguno o puede ser cualquiera) mientras que una función con un único parámetro anónimo de tipo `void` se considera que no recibe parámetros.

Comment: Por más que tienes razón, a mi el programa dado por el usuario me funciona sin errores de compilación. ¿Será este uno de esos comportamientos indefinidos? Lo cierto es que yo he escrito en incontables ocasiones, antes de saber que debía declarar los argumentos, un `int main()` como el del usuario y nunca he tenido problemas...

Comment: @abulafia he añadido una parte del apartado 5.1.2.2.1 que había dejado fuera por pereza: el compilador puede elegir aceptar otras firmas de `main`. Otros compiladores o el mismo compilador en diferente versión o el mismo compilador con diferentes opciones puede aceptar indistintamente `int main()` o `int main(void)`.